# CodeIgniter routes not working properly in Google App Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I have to deploy an old SPA and API to google app engine, so I've split them into 2 services.
But the API is not working properly.

The API is writting in PHP using CodeIgniter, if I write the dispatch.yaml like this

```
dispatch: 
  - url: "*/supplier/*"
    service: api
  - url: "*/user/*"
    service: api
```

So the routes are something like `domain.com/supplier/` and it properly calls the class from controllers/Supplier.php and so on. But the point is trying to run this with a dispatch.yaml configuration like this one

```
dispatch: 
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: api
```

But the actual behavior is when accessing `domain.com/api/supplier/` it loads the class from controllers/Api.php

Comment: what App Engine environment are you using(standard or flexible)?, did you follow a guide?

Comment: Standard, no guide followed, just looking through the docs and internet.

Comment: I can see that all your requests send to the same service, please check the document "dispatch.yaml Configuration File." and verify if this is what you are looking forhttps://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/reference/dispatch-yaml